# Is there any drawback of using Internal Impala table vs External Impala table?

Tags: cloudera, impala

We know of following advantage of using internal tables;

1. Internal table provides merge functionality (update single column)
2. Query optimization and query cache

Are there any drawbacks of using Internal Tables?

Answer (score 0):

Most apps uses internal tables to get benefit of impala. Most importantly, you/hive are the owner of the table and not someone else.
I have seen people uses external table is when they want to use less expensive staging area or reading from some external file not a part of warehouse. But for target data/final data, we should use internal table which are managed/owned by hive/impala.

If you have very good test case for using non managed tables, you can go for it, but i would strongly recommend to use internal.